# xcode : how to display triangle of "*" in ios simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i am trying practice to make different kinds of triangle in Xcode.
i tried to make simple triangle and display it to the iOS simulator.but i failed every time.

i am trying to get some kind of output as below.

```
*
* *
* * *
* * * *
* * * * *
```

i know the logic of it,but i don't know how to display it to the simulator.this is my code with that i am trying to achieve the output.

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%i",*);

    for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
        txtview.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i ",*];
    }

    txtview.text=@"/n";
 }
```

i am currently trying with the textview.i know it is totally wrong because textview always display the last object of for-loop.
but what can i do,if i want to display such kind of output in simulator?
what kind of controls should i use if textview is not working?
please help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you getting now

Comment: you're not printing * anywhere in the program. You're printing the value of j

Comment: nothing.because first i give value of 'j' to the textview and then i gives '\n' to the textview.because of  it ,it returns blank.

Comment: sorry...vijeesh! it is my typing mistake...i already edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the existing text each time.  Instead append to a mutable string object, using a newline character to separate the lines:

```
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString new];
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%i",i);

    for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)
    {
        [string appendFormat:@"%i ",j];
    }

    [string appendString:@"\n"];
}

txtview.text = string;
```

(Note: it's not clear to me what that code has to do with triangles, however I'll leave it to you to evolve the implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Every time that loop runs, you set `textview.text` to a new value. That means you're not adding new lines to it, you're setting it to a new line each time it goes through.

You want to look at appending your strings to what's already in the `text` property.